# How to persist two entities at the same time with @OneToOne relationship?

Tags: java, persistence, managed-bean, one-to-one

I have two entities `Travel` and `Assurance` with @OneToOne relationship. Both entities must be created via the same interface with a `Save` botton. I use this method:

ManagedBean.java:

```
public String add(){
    newTravel = manager.createTravel(arrivalDate, returnDate, lengthToStay, addToStay, visitPurpose);
    newAssurance = manager.createAssurance(company, assuranceStart, assuranceEnd, newTravel);
    return "Travellers";
}
```

In the database, I found the `Travel_Id` associated to the `Assurance` but The `Assurance_Id` is `null` in the `Travels` Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your relationship is not bilateral (i.e you do not use the `mappedBy` annotation property). If you used one, you would have only one column (either `Travel_Id` or `Assurance_Id`, depending where you put the `mappedBy`).

Also consider doing the saving inside the same transaction, e.g by using the same manager method and setting both side of the relationship.